# What version of cordova comes with IBM Mobile first 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

I have IBM mobilefirst 7.1. I want to know how can I check the version of cordova thats being used in mobilefirst. I saw something called var PLATFORM_VERSION_BUILD_LABEL = '3.6.4' in cordova.js inside the project. I am guessing that this the version of cordova that being used in the mobilefirst. In my machine I gave cordova -v, It said 5.0.0. I have a dependency with ibm bluemix push integration with mobile first hybrid app. Version of cordova supposed to be below the 4.3([push not initilizing when trying to create hybrid android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281772/push-not-initilizing-when-trying-to-create-hybrid-android-application/33282077?noredirect=1#comment54490041_33282077)).

Here are my questions:
How can I see the version of cordova that is in the worklight? 
If I have to downgrade what should I do ?
By downgrading the cordova outside, will it effect anything in the mobilefirst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MobileFirst Platform Foundation bundles Cordova inside it. You cannot replace it in any way (upgrade or downgrade).

MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 uses Cordova 3.6.4.

That v5.0 you see if likely coming from a local installation of Cordova in your workstation and it is unrelated to MobileFirst's.

Comment: Thank you such much for clarifying my doubts on the above question. Can you also please look into the issue that i mentioned above ? "push not initilizing when trying to create hybrid android application" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281772/push-not-initilizing-when-trying-to-create-hybrid-android-application/33282077?noredirect=1#comment54490041_33282077)

Answer (score 1):

You can always check the folder wl/your_project_name/apps/project_name/iphone/native/CordovaLib/ and there will be a file called VERSION. It will show you the exact version. I see version 3.7.0.

Note: this file will show on the native folder once you build your app.